# Can I contribute to an IRA from investment income?

Tags: united-states, investing, income-tax, ira

Can one contribute to IRA if the income for the year is received from stock sale only (no W2)?

What I have been reading is that in order to contribute $X to IRA I need to have earned $X of income, and interest income does not count. How about income from selling stocks?
If you could provide reference to some more information online that would be wonderful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your contributions must come from "compensation". Quoting [IRS Publication 590](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p590.pdf) on IRAs, "Generally, compensation is what you earn from working."

So it is unlikely that your stock sale proceeds, if they're your sole source of income, can be used to fund your IRA.

If you do have W-2 income, or self employment income, you can use the proceeds of a stock sale to fund an IRA. The IRS doesn't care where the exact dollars that go into the IRA come from, only that you earned (from working) at least as much as you contributed.

Comment: Very useful info; found a link online with further information but from someone who has the problem of reaching the upper income limit for contribution:   http://www.bogleheads.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=133378

Comment: @user2686641 For _Traditional_ IRAs, there is _no_ upper income limit for _contributions_; but there is a limit beyond which Traditional IRA contributions are _not deductible from current income._

Answer (score 3):

Traditional IRA contributions can be made if you
have *compensation* and the amount of the contribution is limited
to the smaller of your *compensation* and $5500 ($6000 if age 50 or more).
Note that *compensation* (which generally means *earnings from working*)
is not just what appears on a W-2 form as salary or wages; it can be
earnings from self-employment too,
as well as commissions, alimony etc (but not earnings from property,
pensions and annuities, certain types of partnership income)
You must also not have attained age 70.5 in the year for which the
contribution is made.

Even if you don't have any compensation of your own, you
can nonetheless make a Traditional IRA contribution if your *spouse*
has compensation as long as you are filing a joint tax return
with your spouse. For spouses filing a joint return, the
limits are still the same $5500/$6000 for each spouse, and the
sum total of Traditional IRA contributions for both spouses also must
not exceed the sum total of earned income of both spouses.
The age limits etc are all still applicable.

Note that none of this says anything about whether the contributions
are *deductible.*  Everyone meeting the above requirements is eligible
to *make* contributions to a Traditional IRA; whether the contributions
can be *deducted* from current income depends on the income:
those with high enough incomes cannot *deduct* the contribution.
This is different from Roth IRAs to which
people with high incomes are not permitted to make a contribution at all.

Finally, the *source* of
the cash you contribute to the IRA can be the proceeds of the stock sale
if you like;
you are not required to prove that the cash received from compensation is
what you sent to the IRA custodian.

Read Publication 590 (available on the IRS website [www.irs.gov](http://www.irs.gov)) if you need
an authoritative reference.

Comment: Necroed updates: per TCJA, _alimony_ from a divorce decree/settlement established or modified in 2019 or later is no longer compensation; per SECURE, as of 2020 the age limit of 70.5 to contribute is repealed, and the age for RMD is increased to 72 (and per CARES, for 2020 _only_ RMD is waived entirely).